# Знаки препинания в предложении (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, егэ

*Экономической свободы для каждого человека нет и, судя по всему, быть не может, но свободных людей — огромное множество*.

Нужно объяснить постановку каждой запятой и тире.

Comment: Правильное предложение выглядит так: *Полной социальной свободы нет нигде в мире, экономической свободы для каждого человека нет и, судя по всему, быть не может; но свободных людей – огромное множество* (С. Л. Соловейчик). https://bibliopskov.ru/soloveichik.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А какие затруднения?
"Судя по всему" - вводное словосочетание и должно быть выделено запятыми.
Запятая перед "но" разделяет две части сложного предложения.
Тире во второй части предложения логически выделяет сказуемое "огромное множество" (а подлежащее при этом - "людей").
Может возникнуть вопрос о запятой перед "и". Запятая там не нужна - в обороте "нет и быть не может" она не ставится, т.к. это однородные члены (первое сказуемое "нет", а второе - "быть не может").

Comment: Подлежащее всегда в именительном падеже и это не может быть"людей".

Comment: какое же тогда подлежащее в предложении "сорок тысяч обезьян в жопу сунули банан"?
я ошибся, и, действительно, в том предложении подлежащее и сказуемое - другие. Но с вашим утверждением поспорят даже третьеклассники.

Comment: Хорошо, что признаете ошибку. Я в курсе про такие конструкции, это пожалуй единственное исключение из правила и явно не наш случай.